# Styling form in jQuery-Dialog

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

On my jQuery - Dialog I have a form with multiple form fields. There I have a link to add "Attributes". Now I want to have this on the left side of the dialog and on the same line like the submit button. The div "somediv" must be an inline-element.

How can I achieve that?

**jsFiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/Auzx6/
(Please expand the "Result" frame a lot.)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a  `<br clear="all" />` before the div actions (`<div class="actions">`) should make the trick.

The clear="all" will clean all the previous floats.
Then if you want it on the left side just add this css rule "text-align: left" on that div.